# How to update Recyclerview in real-time when a document is removed from firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update Recyclerview in realtime when a document is added or removed from firestore. I am using this logic in **Kotlin:**

```
        for (doc in docs!!.documentChanges) {
            val classElement: FireClassModel=doc.document.toObject(FireClassModel::class.java)

            if (doc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                adapterList.add(classElement)

            } else if(doc.type == DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED){
                adapterList.remove(classElement)
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
```

Its working fine when document is added but it does not work when data is removed. It has no error but it doesn't update in real-time. It only updates when I restart the Application.

**Updated**

**FireClassModel:**

```
class FireClassModel {

    var classID: String = ""
    var className: String = ""


}
```

I tried this `classesList.contains(classElement)` and it returns false. It means I am unable to compare objects in my ArrayList.

Comment: You say "it does not work when data is removed". Do you have an error?

Comment: No error but it doesn't update in real-time..

Comment: "it doesn't update in real-time" but it does update in any other way? Or it doesn't update at all?

Comment: It updates when I restart the application.

Comment: In this case, please update your question and add more code, like the place where you are using the code above.

Comment: You could log the return value of `adapterList.remove(classElement)`. If it is `false`, the element is not present in the list.

Comment: @MarkusPenguin bro if it is present in the list then why is it showing in adapter?

Comment: @ShahzadAkram just log it. The result may surprise you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but it seems that the element that you are trying to remove from the list cannot be found there.

```
adapterList.remove(classElement)
```

When removing an element from a list using `remove(o: Object): Boolean` the first *matching element from the list* will be removed. A matching element is an element where the `equals` method returns `true`.

```
listElement == elementToRemove // Kotlin
listElement.equals(elementToRemove); // Java
```

By default (that means if you do not override `equals`) objects will only be equal, if they share the same location in memory. In your example the element in the list sits at a different location than the element that you create from Firestore in your document change listener.

The solution depends on your `FireClassModel`. Looking at multiple `FireClassModel` objects, how would you decide which two of them are equal? Maybe they'll have the same id? Then override the `equals` method (and per contract also `hashCode`) and compare the fields that make two objects identical. For an id, the solution could look like that (generated by Android Studio):

```
class FireClassModel(val id: Int) {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

        other as FireClassModel

        if (id != other.id) return false

        return true
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return id
    }
}
```

After that comparing two `FireClassModel` objects with the same ID will return `true`. Without overriding the `equals` method that would not be the case (unless you comparing an object to itself).

More about `equals` can be found on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520464/2143225) and in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Comment: Bro thanks, now I am getting your point, as you mentioned I tried this `classesList.contains(classElement)` and it returns false. I have added some more info in my question please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have solved the issue. The issue was, I am not getting the right object.

I just replaced `adapterList.remove(classElement)` with following:

```
            for (cls in adapterList) {
                if (cls.classID == doc.document.id) {
                    adapterList.remove(cls)
                }
            }
```

Thanks to @Markus