# get data from Firestore and load recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I am using `recyclerView` to load data from Firestore. I want my `recyclerView` to get updated whenever a document gets added or deleted in the Firestore database without reloading the activity/fragment. Is there any way I can achieve this?

objects:

```
private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
private var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>? = null
private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var userArrayList: ArrayList<User>
```

its in fragment so

```
override fun onViewCreated(itemView: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(itemView, savedInstanceState)
    userArrayList = arrayListOf()
    eventChangeListener()

}
```

pulling data:

```
private fun eventChangeListener() {
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    db.collection("Users").addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
        override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
            if (error != null){
                Log.e("firestore error", error.message.toString())
                return
            }
            for (dc : DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!){
                if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                    userArrayList.add(dc.document.toObject(User::class.java))
                }
            }
            callBack()
        }


    })
}
```

populating

```
private fun callBack() {
    holder.apply { //recycler view id
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity,2)
        adapter = RecyclerAdapter(userArrayList)
        this.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Comment: "Any ideas?" is not a great question for us to help with, as we have no way to know what the problem is. When you run this code, what doesn't work the way you expect it to? Even better: when you set a breakpoint on every line and then run in the debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: Yes indeed, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I want it to get updated as soon as the document get added/deleted in Firestore. so far its not updating until I refresh activity. sorry for if it wasn't clear

Comment: There is a very similar question in SO here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483653/how-to-update-recyclerview-in-real-time-when-a-document-is-removed-from-firestor?rq=1) that you might find helpful.